# Fluent validation. Can't find an extension method

Tags: c#, validation, extension-methods, fluentvalidation

I added FluentValidation assembly reference to my project. While writing simple validators there were no problems at all. Problem appeared when I tried to write collection validator. `VisualStudio` doesn't see no `SetCollectionValidator` extension method. Also it doesn't appear inside intellisense snippet. 
I didn't forget to include `using FlentValidation`.

**EDIT**

Despite no intellisense hints the same code builds in SharpDevelop project.

```
public class PostValidator : AbstractValidator<Entities.Post>
{
    public PostValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.Title).NotNull().NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(p => p.Content).NotNull().NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(p => p.Timestamp).NotNull();
    }
}
public class BlogValidator : AbstractValidator<Entities.Blog>
{
    public BlogValidator()
    {            
        RuleFor(b => b.Title).NotNull();
        RuleFor(b => b.Posts).SetCollectionValidator(new PostValidator());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. The project builds, but the SetCollectionValidator method does not appear in intellisense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. It was my mistake. Probably FluentValidation 2.x release doesn't define the extension method. And my #develop project contains FluentValidation 3.x release so it builds perfect. But there's still no intellisese showing the method both in #develop and VS.

Comment: Similarly, for me I installed the latest FluentValidation.WebApi and this caused the 'FluentValidation' package to update, but it left my 'FluentValidation.Mvc5' behind on an older version. Updating the MVC5 package to latest solved the issue for me.